# Starting Docker On Debian 8: No Sockets Found

Tags: docker, debian

I've just tried to install Docker via the [instructions from their site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/debian/#debian-jessie-80-64-bit). After starting the service a call to `docker version` reports the daemon isn't running.  Doing a `ps -ef | grep docker` and I can see that Docker was run using `/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://`.  If I and try to run that manually, I get `FATA[0000] No sockets found`.

There's an [issue about this in Fedora](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11135) and it recommended removing the `-H fd://` option. But I can't spot that anywhere (not in `/etc/init.d/docker`, `/etc/default/docker`, etc).

Can anyone help me get past this issue please?

Answer (score 3):

Right, found it.  Following the advice from the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/), I ran:

```
sudo systemctl status docker | grep Loaded
```

That showed me the defaults came from `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`.  After that I copied the contents of that file to `/etc/system.d/system/docker.service`, overriding the bits I wanted (and removing the items that remained the same).  After that, I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and now the Docker service is using the right command.

Still doesn't solve why my Docker instance doesn't appear to be running though...

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you, please, manage to find a way to have the docker daemon running?